# How to install Python 3, pip, setuptools, virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper in CentOS 7

Tags: bash, python-3.x, centos, pip, virtualenv

So how you install all this software in a Centos 7?

The code below, need to be run with root.

Just follow this simple steps.

```
sudo su -
nano script
    paste the script and change the variable USER
chmod 755 script
./script
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to solve all this issues.

If you need the gist, here is the link:

https://gist.github.com/edutopy/7f66a2b9522bec7aa4e4

```
#!/bin/bash

## IMPORTANT ##
# Run this script with root (sudo su -), wont work if run as sudo.
# Change the variables as needed. 
######################################################################

USER=sysadmin # User that will have ownership (chown) to /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib
USERHOME=/home/${USER} # The path to the users home, in this case /home/youruser
PYSHORT=3.5 # The Python short version, e.g. easy_install-${PYSHORT} = easy_install-3.5
PYTHONVER=3.5.1 # The actual version of python that you want to download from python.org

cd ${USERHOME}
# Install development tools and some misc. necessary packages
yum -y groupinstall "Development tools"
yum -y install zlib-devel  # gen'l reqs
yum -y install bzip2-devel openssl-devel ncurses-devel  # gen'l reqs
yum -y install mysql-devel  # req'd to use MySQL with python ('mysql-python' package)
yum -y install libxml2-devel libxslt-devel  # req'd by python package 'lxml'
yum -y install unixODBC-devel  # req'd by python package 'pyodbc'
yum -y install sqlite sqlite-devel xz-devel 
yum -y install readline-devel tk-devel gdbm-devel db4-devel 
yum -y install libpcap-devel xz-devel # you will be sad if you don't install this before compiling python, and later need it.

# Alias shasum to == sha1sum (will prevent some people's scripts from breaking)
echo 'alias shasum="sha1sum"' >> ${USERHOME}/.bashrc

# Install Python ${PYTHONVER} (do NOT remove 2.7, by the way)
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHONVER}/Python-${PYTHONVER}.tgz
tar -zxvf Python-${PYTHONVER}.tgz 
cd ${USERHOME}/Python-${PYTHONVER}
./configure --prefix=/usr/local LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath /usr/local/lib" --with-ensurepip=install
make && make altinstall

# Install virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper
cd ${USERHOME}
chown -R ${USER} /usr/local/bin
chown -R ${USER} /usr/local/lib
easy_install-${PYSHORT} virtualenv
easy_install-${PYSHORT} virtualenvwrapper
echo "export WORKON_HOME=${USERHOME}/.virtualenvs" >>  ${USERHOME}/.bashrc # Change this directory if you don't like it
echo "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/local/bin/python3.5" >> ${USERHOME}/.bashrc
echo "export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_VIRTUALENV=/usr/local/bin/virtualenv" >> ${USERHOME}/.bashrc
echo 'source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh' >> ${USERHOME}/.bashrc # Important, don't change the order.
source ${USERHOME}/.bashrc

mkdir -p ${WORKON_HOME}
chown -R ${USER} ${WORKON_HOME}
chown -R ${USER} ${USERHOME}

# Done!
# Now you can do: `mkvirtualenv foo`
```